# Problem when retrieving data from a website and switching screen on React Native

Tags: react-native, https, expo

so, I was trying to get a sort of type of a login on React Native that actually retrieves data from a real website, but I have this problem when I want to switch from a screen to another, because it does not change to the other screen:

```
    responseFromWeb = () => { 
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var response;

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {        
            alert(xhttp.responseText);
            this.setState({ info: xhttp.responseText });
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { info: this.state.info }) 
          }
        };
        xhttp.open(
          'GET',
          'http://dcc.000webhostapp.com/2020a/datosudeg.php?codigo=' +
            this.state.codigo +
            '&nip=' +
            this.state.nip,
          true
        );
        xhttp.send();

        this.setState({ codigo: '', nip: '' });   

      };
```

Now, I know that, in this situation, those ***'this'*** under the alert are not accesing the *class* properties, and they're accesing the **xhttp** var properties, and I really don't know how to access the *class* properties instead of *xhttps*

I tried with making another function that first calls **responseFromWeb()** and then navigate to the other screen, but it loads the Profile screen before I get the web response, and I need to use that information in a Text component from the start of the Profile screen. Am I doing something *terribly* wrong?

Comment: By the way, if `this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { info: this.state.info })` is out of that function, it works fine (it changes the screen), but that way I can't get the information that I want passed through to the other screen. I don't know if I asked this well, so any doubts, please tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I know that, in this situation, those 'this' under the alert are not accesing the class properties, and they're accesing the xhttp var properties, and I really don't know how to access the class properties instead of xhttps

You can use arrow functions to not shadow outer `this`, e.g.

```
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
      // xhttp refers to xhttp
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {        
        alert(xhttp.responseText);
        // this refers to a component
        this.setState({ info: xhttp.responseText });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { info: this.state.info }) 
      }
    };
```

But really there is no reason to use outdated `XMLHttpRequest`, use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) combined with promises or async/await for cleaner syntax instead